# Tkinter import filedialog error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use tkinter with python3 to open an image, see here a piece of code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# --- Python 3.4

from PIL import Image
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import os
var = 'n'

# Importing the image to correct

while var != 'o' :
    var = raw_input("Press \"o\" to open the image to correct\n")
    var = var.lower()
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
image_test = Image.open(path)
```

I have installed python3-tk, and I have the demo window when I write

```
python3 -m tkinter
```

in the terminal. I tried several combinations that did not work :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
```

gives

```
ImportError : No module named tkinter
```

,

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import filedialog
```

gives

```
ImportError : cannot import name filedialog
```

I tried with _tinker , FileDialog, file_dialog, but I always have "ImportError : cannot import name filedialog". Any clue ?

Comment: Interestingly enough, calling "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" enables you to "import tkinter" and "tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(...)" later. Certainly this is not the preferred way to fix your problem, but it may explain different experience people may have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`tkinter.filedialog` is for Python 3 only.

From your attempts, it seems like you are using `Python 2.x` , try importing `tkFileDialog`

Example -

```
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
```

---

Or alternatively, check why it ends up running Python 2.x , instead of Python 3.x .

`Tkinter` module is only there in python 2 , python 3 has `tkinter` module, since when importing `Tkinter` it is successfully getting imported, but when importing `tkinter` it is failing to import it, we can be sure you end up running Python 2.x and not Python 3.

You can do -

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
```

to check the version of python currently running as well as the location of `python` (or `python3`) that is running.

---

Most probably , the issue is occuring because even though you have `python3` shebang line in your script, you are most probably running `python <script.py>` , this always causes python 2 to run.

The aim of adding the `python3` shebang line was to be able to run the script directly, without specifying the executable. For that you would need to do -

1. Give executable permission to the script. (Use `chmod u+x <script.py>` )
2. Then run the script as - `./<script.py>`

Comment: Indeed it is running python2 : `2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
/usr/bin/python
` I'm trying to figure out how to make it run python3

Comment: It returns `/usr/bin/python3` which I put in the header of your mini code. It still returns 2.7.6 version. I'm considering trying `alias python=python3`

Comment: Try running `/usr/bin/python3` to see if its really python3 , secondly how are you putting it in the header?

Comment: Running it returns `Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux` . I'm quite new on python, what I call "header" is the first 3 lines of my code : `#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# --- Python 3.4`

Comment: I am guessing after adding the `shebang` (thats what the first line of the header is called) , you are trying to run using `python <script>` , this would always run python 2, the reason you added shebang was to be able to run without having to specify the executable, just run - `./<script>.py` or run - `python3 script.py` .

Comment: You are right, thanks. I guess Geany is using `python` command instead of `python3` , i will try to change that, or use `alias` as mentionned above.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `from tkinter import filedialog` alternatively you can try `from tkinter import *` or `import tkinter.filedialog as fd` . If it doesn't work like that, then you should try to reinstall python.

Answer (score 0):

**for above python3**

> `from` tkinter.filedialog `import` askopenfilename

Answer (score 0):

My python version is 3.x and the simple trick that worked for me is

```
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
```