# How to use tkinter and askopenfilename in PyCharm Edu?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I have a code that works in another computer but doesn't in my computer. The part below gives error:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

It says 'unresolved reference'. With some researches and from the suggestions in PyCharm I wrote it as:

```
import _tkinter as Tk
from _tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

It only accepts _tkinter. But I still cannot import askopenfilename. It says 'unresolved reference'. Should I have done anything else before to import tkinter?

By the way, we have different IDE's. I have PyCharm Edu. Can that be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter import filedialog error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669945/tkinter-import-filedialog-error)

Comment: You definitely should not be importing `_tkinter`. Please [edit] your question to include the actual error and traceback.